# Drawing to a buffered image inside a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, jpanel

i am currently trying to make a canvas that i can draw stuff to and have it appear inside a JFrame.

To do this, i intend to have a BufferedImage inside a JPanel component that the paintComponent method can draw from.

Ideally from the given JFrame i want to be able to reference this buffered image, and then draw stuff to it using its Graphics2D that the paintComponent method can then show when it draws using the buffered image.

I'm doing this to avoid using the paintcomponent method directly, i want to be able to reference this canvas from anywhere in the program and have it be painted when the frames repaint() method is called.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D  imgG2 = img.createGraphics();

    public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
        return imgG2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    }
}
class Main {

private static JFrame createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("droneFrame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(new MyPanel());
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      return frame;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = createAndShowGui();

    //Something here to reference the inner Jpanels imgG2 field, and draw to it.

    frame.repaint();
    //Draw whatever is currently in the buffered image.
}
}
```

However, i'm at a loss at how to do this, since frame.getComponent(0) just returns a Component, rather than the specfic type of component it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Ideally from the given JFrame i want to be able to reference this buffered image"* - I wouldn't think this was idea for a number of reasons; 1- It's coupling your code; 2- It could cause graphical glitches, depending on how you're updating the image, as you could be updating the image while the component is drawing it

Comment: A better solution might be to have a class whose sole job it was, was to take input from some source, update the image and generate some kind of "update" notification, to which the rendering engine (i.e. your `JPanel`) could listen to and then repaint the supplied image.  This would allow to implement such things as page flipping as well as decouple of the process, allowing you to modify any link in the pipeline chain any way you wanted to without effecting the other links

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to figure this out, you need to set the content pane of your JFrame to the JPanel, then to reference the graphics of the buffered image, you need to get the content pane of the JFrame, and downcast it to the specific type MyPanel.

Now you have the content pane in the correct format, and can reference the graphics since it now has that field.

Comment: You've made a number of assumptions about the state of your program which could cause you any number of issues in the long term, sure it's a "personal project", but it's even more important to investigate quality coding practices in these cases as it builds good habits.  Down casting is problematic at the best of times, better to deal with known types as much as possible (relying on interfaces if possible) - IMHO